# Can someone help me out in solve problem create test page by test user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

by my developer account, I created a test user. In the test user login, I am trying to create a test page. I followed all documentation to the dot. However I am getting the following error
GraphQL server responded with error 1373073

I have waited a whole day before I tried again.
Still same error. Can someone help me out?